# How to push new constructor properties to array?

Tags: javascript

Lets say i have constructor function person and created same type of object using new now i want to push these values to array. How can i do that using javaScript ?

ctrl.js

```
var personArray = [];
function person(firstname,lastname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname= lastname;
    this.fullName = function (){
        return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname
    }
}
var sam = new person("Sam","Martin");
var john = new person("John","Martin");

personArray.push(sam.fullName(),john.fullName());
console.log(personArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the objects, not their names.

```
personArray.push(sam, john);
```